# Possible to Hide Shipped orders in default Order view?

Tags: php, opencart, opencart-3

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to hide the orders marked as shipped from the default view when I go to my orders. This would be similar to how "missing orders" isn't in the default view but needs to be clicked on from the dropdown list.

I don't see the need to have historical orders in the list mostly because I find myself having to scroll too often to get to some orders that haven't been shipped yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you need to add a bit to the sql query for listing orders. Here is a mod that hides order status ID 3 (which should be shipped) unless its chosen from the dropdown:

```
<id><![CDATA[Not Display Shipped order status.]]></id>
<version><![CDATA[1.0.0]]></version>
<vqmver><![CDATA[2.4.1]]></vqmver>
<author><![CDATA[Mujahid Bhoraniya - bhoraniyamujahid@gmail.com]]></author>



<!-- @GLOBAL CONTROLLER -->
<file name="admin/model/sale/order.php">

    <operation info="make query choose all orders except missing and shipped" error="log">
        <search position="replace"><![CDATA[
            $sql .= " WHERE o.order_status_id > '0'";
        ]]></search>
        <add><![CDATA[
        $sql .= " WHERE o.order_status_id > '0' && o.order_status_id != '3'";
        ]]></add>
    </operation>

    <operation info="make query choose all orders except missing and shipped" error="log">
        <search position="replace" index="1"><![CDATA[
            $sql .= " WHERE order_status_id > '0'";
        ]]></search>
        <add><![CDATA[
        $sql .= " WHERE order_status_id > '0' && order_status_id != '3'";
        ]]></add>
    </operation>

</file>
```

Answer (score 0):

**OCMOD - Solutions**

You can copy below code and create new `install.xml` file

```
<name><![CDATA[Admin Not Display Shipped order status in order list]]></name>
<code><![CDATA[Admin Not Display Shipped order status in order list]]></code>
<version><![CDATA[3.x]]></version>
<author><![CDATA[Dhaupin - CreadevDotOrg]]></author>



<!-- @GLOBAL CONTROLLER -->
<file path="admin/model/sale/order.php">

    <operation info="make query choose all orders except missing and shipped" error="log">
        <search><![CDATA[
            $sql .= " WHERE o.order_status_id > '0'";
        ]]></search>
        <add position="replace"><![CDATA[
        $sql .= " WHERE o.order_status_id > '0' && o.order_status_id != '3'";
        ]]></add>
    </operation>

    <operation info="make query choose all orders except missing and shipped" error="log">
        <search><![CDATA[
            $sql .= " WHERE order_status_id > '0'";
        ]]></search>
        <add  position="replace" index="1"><![CDATA[
        $sql .= " WHERE order_status_id > '0' && order_status_id != '3'";
        ]]></add>
    </operation>

</file>
```

after You can make zip file install.xml file. it name `Shipped.ocmod.zip`